# How to concatenate arrays grouped by another column in Presto?

Tags: sql, presto, trino

Is this possible in SQL (preferably Presto):

I want to reshape this table:

```
id, array
1, ['something']
1, ['something else']
2, ['something']
```

To this table:

```
id, array
1, ['something', 'something else']
2, ['something']
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Presto you can use `array_agg`. Assuming that on input, all your `array`s are single-element, this would look like this:

```
select id, array_agg(array[0])
from ...
group by id;
```

If, however, your input arrays are not necessarily single-element, you can combine this with `flatten`, like this:

```
select id, flatten(array_agg(array))
from ...
group by id;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want an array that shows the distinct items in the aggregated array then this should work:

```
select id, array_distinct(flatten(array_agg(array))) as array
from ...
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do `set_union` if you only need distinct values

```
select id, set_union(array) as array
from ...
group by id
```